# Qiskit compute mean expectation value

Tags: qiskit, programming, qaoa

I want to calculate the mean expectation value of an PauliSumOp within qiskit after I executed a QAOA Circuit. My approach is the following:

```
# Run and get counts
job=qiskit.execute(circuit,backend=simulator,shots=shots,optimization_level=0)
result = job.result().get_counts()
# Compute average expectation value of the observable H Ising
max_count=0
value=0
for string,count in result.items():
    value+=count*sum([(~StateFn(string)@ op @ StateFn(string)).eval() for op in hamiltonian])
    max_count+=count
expectation=value/max_count
```

Is this correct? I am especially concerned if `StateFn(Bitstring)` is a valid usage of qiskit in terms of `StateFn("0101")`=$|0101\rangle$

Comment: Could you include the code where you define the ``hamiltonian`` variable? i.e. where you write ``for op in hamiltonian``, could you show how you instantiate that ``PauliSumOp`` object?

Comment: The hamiltonian variable is instantiated by defining a Graph which is supposed to be solved within the MaxCut Problem. With following steps:
`max_cut = Maxcut(Graph)`

`qp = max_cut.to_quadratic_program()`

`hamiltonian=qp.to_ising()`

Returning the hamiltonian gives in my example:
`PauliSumOp(SparsePauliOp(['ZZII', 'IZZI', 'ZIIZ', 'IZIZ', 'IIZZ'],
              coeffs=[0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j]), coeff=1.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `StateFn(Bitstring)` is a valid usage of qiskit in terms of `StateFn("0101")`=$\left|0101\right\rangle$. As an example:

```
>>> from qiskit.opflow import Plus, StateFn
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(Plus.to_circuit())
     ┌───┐
q_0: ┤ H ├
     └───┘
>>> v_zero_one = (StateFn("0") + StateFn("1")) / np.sqrt(2)
>>> print(v_zero_one)
DictStateFn({'0': 1.0, '1': 1.0}) * 0.7071067811865475
>>> np.allclose(Plus.to_matrix(), v_zero_one.to_matrix())
True
```

And yes, to me, the rest of your code looks correct for `hamiltonian` of type `PauliSumOp`.

Answer (score 0):

Qiskit provides a high-level constructs that can be used to calculate the expectation value. You don't have to do this low-level calculations by yourself.

First, use `ExpectationFactory`<sup>[[1]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.expectations.ExpectationFactory.html)</sup> to get a suitable expectation algorithm based on your backend (simulator or actual quantum device) and operator type:

```
exp_converter = ExpectationFactory.build(hamiltonian, simulator)
```

Now, use this expectation converter<sup>[[2]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.expectations.ExpectationBase.html)</sup> and `CircuitSampler`<sup>[[3]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.converters.CircuitSampler.html)</sup> to do the low-level calculations:

```
measurable_expression =  ~StateFn(hamiltonian) @ StateFn(circ)
expect_op = exp_converter.convert(measurable_expression)
sampled_op = CircuitSampler(simulator).convert(expect_op)
expectation_value = sampled_op.eval().real
```

Comment: Is there any ressource to learn qiskit in a way to know these "tricks"? The tutorials and example notebooks were not covering such things, as far as I know.

Comment: You can read about this [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/operators/01_operator_flow.html#Expectations) and [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/algorithms/04_vqe_advanced.ipynb).